# How can I create a SQL table from another table without copying any values from the old table

Tags: sql, oracle

*How to create table with existing table structure without iterate row by row like this in Oracle?* Thanks in Advance.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT *
      FROM old_table WHERE 1=2);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your Answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried about iterating through the table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT *
      FROM (select * old_table where rownum = 1) t
      WHERE 1=2
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already read about this.. Hope it gives a Detailed explanation to you..

*What we ended up doing in this clients case was to replace the “WHERE 1=2” with a clause that equated the primary key of the table with an impossible value for that key, in this case the ID was being passed in as a GUID (a hexadecimal value) so we use a “WHERE KEY=HEX(00)” and got a low cost unique index lookup instead of a costly full table scan.*

http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_ault_where_1_equals_2_parallel_.htm

Thanks to `Burleson Consulting`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the exact Oracle syntax but in virtually any SQL if you open up the other table using a GUI tool there are options both to generate a create script statement for the table and to backup the table without data.

Either of those will do what you need.

Comment: In the case of oracle, sqldeveloper might the software you need to do this.